# Delete remote branch in SAP Web IDE

Tags: git, git-branch, sap-web-ide, remote-branch

I created a remote Branch but with the wrong name and now I want to delete the remote branch. The problem is I don't now how because if I right-click one the Project->Git there is only an option to create a remote branch but no option to delete one.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the repo locally and simply run:

```
git push origin --delete branch_to_delete
```

Comment: You can’t. That’s why you need to clone the repo locally. You can download Git from https://git-scm.com/downloads if you haven’t installed it yet.

Comment: So far so good, your advice helped me a lot. 
My problem now is, that I used a "ö" in the name "Modul-Löschung", so in the console the name is: remotes/origin/Modul-L<C3><83><C2><B6>schung but I can't delete such a name because "<" is unexcepted. I tried to delete "Modul-Löschung" but the console says, that this remote ref does not exist.

Comment: You should see your remote branch name if you log in to the SCP and on the left side menu navigate to Repositories > Git Repositories > Click on the name of the repo > Click on the Repository Browser URL

There you can see all your remote branches under "Branches" on the left side. Please verify that your branch "Modul-Löschung" is still there. If it is not. Than you successfully deleted the remote branch.